# iOS is exit(0) deprecated?

Tags: iphone, ios

Does anyone know if `exit(0)` is deprecated in iOS application? I know it is not a good decision to manually terminate the app, but does Apple ban the application if we use it in the code?

Comment: apple just stats that it is not a good solution, and you should inform the user about what is going to happen. You Could show an Alert and wait for the user to confirm the dialog before calling exit.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you think requires you to call exit(0)? Tell us why you are trying to run it and there will almost definitely be a way around it that maybe you haven't discovered. You should never call exit(0) from an app.

Comment: I had an app rejected for using exit(0). They said it was because it made it look like the app had crashed to the user, cause i was not notifying them of the exit or why. So I would say it wasn't really because of that really but they did advice to remove it. "It would be appropriate to remove any mechanisms for quitting your app."

Comment: What i am trying to do is manually disable multitasking, so if the application goes into background, it simply terminate itself. The reason for doing this is that the App is really old, so it does not fully support multitasking, but we do not have enough time to change the code and test it for incoming update. However the new facebook sdk requires multitasking to login (the old delegate method fbdidLogin() does not work anymore, and I can not find a solution for this issue on google), so we have to enable multitasking temporarily to perform the login.

Comment: It's not deprecated, it's prohibited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got an app which was rejected because of a way of exit (via UIAlertView), doing an `exit(5)`  when user click on the correct button.

I received that:

> We found that your app includes a UI control for quitting the app.
>   This is not in compliance with the iOS Human Interface Guidelines, as
>   required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Please refer to the attached screenshot/s for reference.
>
> The iOS Human Interface Guidelines specify,
>
> "Always Be Prepared to Stop iOS applications stop when people press
>   the Home button to open a different application or use a device
>   feature, such as the phone. In particular, people don’t tap an
>   application close button or select Quit from a menu. To provide a good
>   stopping experience, an iOS application should:
>
> - Save user data as soon as possible and as often as reasonable because an exit or terminate notification can arrive at any time.
> - Save the current state when stopping, at the finest level of detail possible so that people don’t lose their context when they start the
>     application again. For example, if your app displays scrolling data,
>     save the current scroll position."
>
> It would be appropriate to remove any mechanisms for quitting your
>   app.

A "hidden" exit could be understood as a crash for the user, no?

Comment: And if the exit isn't "hidden" but an obvious result of a specific user action?

Comment: Well, my rejection was cause because of an obvious action! I said I had an `UIAlertview` with a button saying Exit....

Comment: Who is upvoting your comments @HotLicks ! Please understand exiting in this manor is such a terrible thing, I feel violated, I feel like the developer is crashing my phone, I feel the pain for my phone and the first thing that pops into my mind is, oh my, need to delete app before it hacks anything. Of course then I'm the developer and know that's not going to happen, the average user doesn't.

Comment: I completely agree Daniel, and although this answer does provide insight, it does not answer the original question and instead asks it's own question... Why it was chosen as the answer is beyond me. For the people reading this Q/A, please read my post even if this poster doesn't agree it is the "answer". The knowledge found in the HIG should be where you look for your answer, not here.

Comment: @MarkM: Sorry, for the misunderstanding, but my last question was rhetorical.

Answer (score 6):

No, Apple will not reject your app for using `exit(0)`.

You are correct, it is not a great design choice, but it can be useful sometimes.

As Larme mentioned, if used incorrectly, it can be perceived as a crash and a crash will result in your app being rejected.

However, it can be very useful in `applicationDidEnterBackground` when (on a conditional basis ) you might want to force the app to start a fresh.

Comment: It's about the only way I know of to handle "decline" in a license acceptance dialog.

Comment: Why would you ever need to exit the app for a decline license dialog? Allow for a retry if that is the case and on fail do not allow to proceed and display another dialogue. If the user decides to close the app completely they still have the power to do so.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my answer incorrect? I can tell you from experience that Apple will not reject your app on the sole fact of `exit` being called somewhere in your code.

Comment: @MarkM - If they declined, why would they want to retry?  In the odd case that they accidentally declined they can simply restart the app.  If the user just presses the button the app is (at least by default) backgrounded, and few users know how to actually kill an app from there.

Comment: The problem is calling exit in the first place, not the reasoning behind why you want to call it. You are arguing against Apple's guidelines, not mine. ;-) You are mistaken if you think I agree 100% wholeheartedly with every decision Apple makes. Sometimes the logical solution to you and I is not the logical solution or agreed upon solution by Apple.

Comment: I included the answer to your argument in my previous answer since it appears many people still need to read the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: Jason, you are arguing a moot point. Read the HIG and then tell me I am wrong. What am I missing here? LOL. Did you even read my answer?!?!? It clearly says to NEVER call exit. In the circumstance of a decline dialogue it is clearly stated you should have this as part of your EULA and never ask the user to agree after installing the App. Do your homework first before saying someone is "wrong". "If possible, provide a disclaimer within your app description or EULA. Users can then view the disclaimer in the App Store, and you can balance business requirements with user experience needs."

Comment: Also Jason, explain a time when you should call exit during applicationDidEnterBackground so others can understand why you are even posting this as an answer to this question? It seems your app design is flawed from the start if you are even needing to call exit from ADEB. The simple fact is your answer is wrong and misleading. "No, Apple will not reject your app for using exit(0)."

Comment: @MarkM - I know of several apps that *do* use exit(0) and have not been rejected.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, and there have also been Apps approved that contained malware, lockups, copyrighted data and a billion other wrong ways to do things. Does that make it correct or HIG compliant? "does Apple ban the application if we use the code?". Yes, if it is found... Better? ;-)

Comment: that is what I did actually, just to terminate the App manually when it goes into background.

Comment: Thanks @user1898387, if you found my answer helpful I would really appreciate it if you marked it as "the answer". Thanks! :-)

Comment: Oh @HotLicks please take that back, this is the WORST way to handle a license acceptance dialog, when I arrived in my new job as a lead iOS developer I checked the git history for an app doing this and got the guy fired for it. Don't do it.

Comment: Even if you don't like to show the EULA before the user downloads the app (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843774/ios-is-exit0-deprecated#comment19060912_13843975 ) there is absolutely no need to exit the app ever. 1. You could show a default screen detailing that additional information has to be filled out before the user can continue. 2. If you *need* to quite the app when going in to background for getting a clean state, fix the bugs why you need that clean state. Everything else is a horrible user experience, implementation and against the HIG no matter what excuse you search for.

Answer (score 5):

No, you must not call exit as your app ***SHOULD*** be rejected. This has been repeatedly discouraged by Apple and is known to cause serious bugs with iOS multitask switching. You should simply leave the user to use the home button themselves.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html

"Additionally, data may not be saved, because -applicationWillTerminate: and similar UIApplicationDelegate methods will not be invoked if you call exit. If DURING DEVELOPMENT or TESTING it is necessary to terminate your application, the abort function, or assert macro is recommended."

2012-04-09
Updated to more strongly discourage the exit function, and include best practices for debugging.

2008-08-27
New document that discusses best practices for terminating an iOS application in code.

Straight from the iOS Human Interface Guidelines
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27

"Don’t Quit Programmatically

Never quit an iOS app programmatically because people tend to interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent your app from functioning as intended, you need to tell your users about the situation and explain what they can do about it. Depending on how severe the app malfunction is, you have two choices.

Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a correction. A screen provides feedback that reassures users that there’s nothing wrong with your app. It puts users in control, letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and continue using your app or press the Home button and open a different app

If only some of your app's features are unavailable, display either a screen or an alert when people use the feature. Display the alert only when people try to access the feature that isn’t functioning.

If Necessary, Display a License Agreement or Disclaimer

If you provide an end-user license agreement (or EULA) with your iOS app, the App Store displays it so that people can read it before they get your app.

If possible, avoid requiring users to indicate their agreement to your EULA when they first start your app. Without an agreement displayed, users can enjoy your app without delay. However, even though this is the preferred user experience, it might not be feasible in all cases. If you must display a license agreement within your app, do so in a way that harmonizes with your user interface and causes the least inconvenience to users.

If possible, provide a disclaimer within your app description or EULA. Users can then view the disclaimer in the App Store, and you can balance business requirements with user experience needs."

Comment: Even Apple says that calling `exit` isn't what the issue is, it's the perception of the app crashing. In isolation of "can I call exit", the answer is "possibly".

Comment: @JasonWhitehorn Please read the document I posted as I believe you are leading people to believe incorrect information. There are other reasons Apple discourages this behavior and will reject your app. "Additionally, data may not be saved, because -applicationWillTerminate: and similar UIApplicationDelegate methods will not be invoked if you call exit. If DURING DEVELOPMENT or TESTING it is necessary to terminate your application, the abort function, or assert macro is recommended."

Comment: Down votes for linking directly to Apple's documents explaining why this is bad and will lead to App rejections. Gotta love S.O. sometimes... If you guys still don't get it PLEASE READ. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27

Comment: I dont understand the down votes. It is true that Apple hate the usage of using `exit()` method in the app and the documentation clearly states that. I dont know how you can bend those lines to make it think that exit is allowed. As per this line, `If you provide an end-user license agreement (or EULA) with your iOS app, the App Store displays it so that people can read it before they get your app`, if you need to show a EULA, there is an option to show that before user installs the app, then why should apple allow a decline button in app.