# quit from iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios6, exit

i have created quit button in iPhone application.and now want when user tap on quit button.the application should enter in background.please provide some suitable solution for this so that i can upload my iPhone app to app store.i have used exit(0).but apple reject my iPhone application.

Comment: That's really bad practice. Apple will keep rejecting your app if you try to implement an "exit" button in your app. The only way the user can exit an app is and must be by pressing the home button.

Comment: apple isn't going to allow the user quits programmatically the app, that's the reason they rejected your app. It's in the apple's HIGs

Comment: never quit an ios app dude...if so why need home button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no methods that will allow you to background the app by code, only the user can background your app by pressing on the home button.

You should really read the [`iOS Human Interface Guidelines`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) especially the part about [`Don’t Quit Programmatically`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)

Comment: actually the problem is that i have created a registration form.in that registration form i have included accept and decline button.for accept the app moves forward ,now for decline button client wants to quit from app.is there any other solution that i can be used on decline button

Comment: Just supply the user with an alertview saying that if they do not accept the term they can't use the app.

Comment: is there any way so that when click on decline,app should suspend or enter in background.

Comment: Like my answer already said: NO

Answer (score 0):

iPhone applications shouldn't have a "Quit" button. If you implement one, you're just asking for rejection. Let the user press the home button to background the application. If you want to terminate when the home button is pressed rather than enter the background state, you can set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that your app got rejected. Didn't they gave you a quote from their Guidelines?
Especially this part: `In particular, people don’t tap an application close button or select Quit from a menu.`
Anyway, you should read this: [iOS is exit(0) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843774/ios-is-exit0-deprecated/13843949#13843949)

Comment: what purpose exit(0) is used for?

Comment: My client had an old app that used the exit(0) in the AppStore. But when I submitted it again for an update, it got rejected for this reason. It's an old legacy...