# How can force update an ios app

Tags: ios

We had developed an ios app and uploaded it to ios server after sometime time some we had done some changes,So new build with new version had uploaded but the users that are having old version is not reflecting with new changes and we had not set any flag or something regard for force update in previous build so can any one tell us how to prevent old version app users to use old version.Please tell how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Handling this through an API would be a better option, call **api** on background thread whenever application becomes active in delegate function i.e. `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{

// call service here

}
```

then check it after receiving response from api that current version is lesser/equal to updated version like,

```
if ([currentAppVersion isEqualToString:versionReceivedFromServer]){

//App is updated

}else{

//App needs to be updated
//Show alert view with only update button and when user tap on it navigate it to you appstore link.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Your Server provide a WebApi to indicate the latest version, and the updating is mandatory or not.

**Step 2**: Your iOS App call that WebApi to get the latest version information. Show a Model View like UIAlertView to inform user that there is a new version, to update it or not? The view provide 2 buttons "YES" and "Later".

- Jump to the AppStore if user chose "YES".
- Close the App by "exit(0)" if user chose "Later" and updating is mandatory. Close the confirm view and do nothing more if updating is not mandatory.

Comment: actually initially we had missed an api and relevent force update code in previous build  so on that case what should we do

Comment: `exit(0)` is not a good idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/13843949/7995508

Comment: means in previous build we dont have api for force update and also not relevant code in ios app though now new build we have done this but if users had downloaded previous the what should do

Comment: Looks no solution for your situation. Why not keep old WebApi for previous version. And develop brand new WebApi like "www.domain.com/api/v2" for new version app? Copy the old WebApi to path v2 might save development time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [appgrades.io](https://appgrades.io) to manage your app versions and convert old version users to the last version. No code needed. Just integrate the SDK in your app and block any version you want with a custom view / alert view that you can customize on appgrades [Dashboard](https://dash.appgrades.io).